# how to limit number of items in a list?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-list

I have a custom list in my sharepoint 2010 site. I want to set a limit to the list, that after reaching the limit(say 10 items), no one can add any more items to that list.
how it can be done.. please tell me how to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think this can be achieve OOTB features of sharepoint .

But i may be possible with the use of some programming

You can use event receiver to achieve this.

1. When an Item is adding in the list check foe the count of a list
2. if count is 10 then cancel the event.

> public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
>       {
>           SPWeb web = properties.OpenWeb();
>           SPList list = web.Lists[properties.ListId];
>           if (list.ItemCount == 10)
>           {
>               properties.Cancel = true;
>           }
>           else
>           {
>               base.ItemAdding(properties);
>           }
>       }

Hope this helps

Comment: you may want to use list.ItemCount >= 10 { cancel } just to be on the safe side.

Comment: If it helped you then please mark it as answer so it may be helpful to others as well